# How to use Python to make a door or bed in Minecraft?

Tags: python, minecraft

I have been using a readable CSV file and a bit of code to generate a fort, but then not a single one of my beds, doors or ladders appeared. Only the back half of my beds actually appeared. For a test I used `setBlock()` to make a bed but again only the back half appeared. How do I make Python realise I want to make it cover 2 blocks?

Comment: I realize this is a really old topic.  However, with all respect to techraf,  Milliways, Steve Robillard, and Jacobmoo1, this question deals with an API for a version of minecraft ONLY avaiable on the Raspberry Pi.

Answer (score 4):

Just as in vanilla Minecraft, you need to [set two blocks to be a bed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/231180/179080) for this to work.

The **vanilla** commands would be:

```
/setblock 0 64 0 bed 0
/setblock 0 64 1 bed 8
```

(for a bed facing north)

You should do something similar in your **Minecraft Pi** Python code:

```
mc.setBlock(x, y, z, 26, 0)
mc.setBlock(x, y, z + 1, 26, 8)
```

Remember the [API](http://www.stuffaboutcode.com/p/minecraft-api-reference.html) for `setBlock` is `setBlock(x,y,z,id,[data])`. The explanation for the data code is available at the [Gamepedia wiki](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Bed#Block_data):

> 0x0   Head facing South
>
> 0x1   Head facing West
>
> 0x2   Head facing North
>
> 0x3   Head facing East
>
> 0x4 (bit flag)    When 0, the bed is empty.
>   When 1, the bed is occupied
>
> 0x8 (bit flag)    When 0, the foot of the bed.
>
> When 1, the head of the bed

The door operates similarly, but with block ID `64` instead, and you'll need to modify the `y` (up/down axis, with positive being up) instead of the `z` (north/south axis, with positive being south).

Comment: I am puzzled, I tried setting two bed blocks next to each other but the result was two back ends of a bed stuck together (if I mines one the other disappeared as well, just like if you placed and mined it with your characters hand) how do I get around this? setBlocks() ? Or is there a way of telling Minecraft to *join* them?

Comment: @user75085 Did you set use the exact example I gave, including the `0` and `8`? That is how you tell the game that one half is the bottom end and one is the top end.